# android aar persist callback to MainActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-library, aar

I have an AAR library and I'm implementing the Google pattern in http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html with an Interface. My problem is when I launch a new activity in this library and I need to recover some data from the main project. When the user opens many others apps,the SO needs to clean memory, so when my app is opened again I have lost the main activity and I'm getting null when trying to get some data from the listener.

This is my class where I put my listener once the fragment is loaded

```
public class ContentCfg {
    private static ContentCfg instance;

    // Listener for handle other modules operations
    private static ContentsMainFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener listener;

    public static synchronized ContentCfg getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ContentCfg();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

As you see the problem is when the instance is null.

My listener is like this

```
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // contact methods
        public String getDisplayNameForUid(String contactUid);
}
```

Main project should search in DB to return data, not just a data I could store in SharePreferences or something like that.

How do you handle this? The AAR doesn't know anything about the main project and his classes. So, how to get info from the main project in another activity in the library?

Thanks